# How to send email with attachment in Android Programmatically sdk 4.0

Tags: android, email, sdk

In my application I want to send email programmatically with out user intervention. I have googled alot and came up with some helpful links given below. But none of them are working for me.

For all of given links:

```
 protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
 return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
```

These lines are not working with error "return type is incompatible" and "constructor is undefined".  Can someone help me to fix the. I have added the required Jar files as well.

[link1](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)

[link2](http://verticalchallenge.org/archives/1906)

[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below lines to your Import.

```
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
```